# How to really switch off ssl verification in git? (http.sslVerify is ignored)

Tags: git, ssl, certificate

There are a million pages describing that switching off ssl verification would solve this problem, but in my case it doesn't:

```bsh
$ git -c http.sslVerify=true pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.mysite.local/bla/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
$ git -c http.sslVerify=false pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.mysite.local/bla/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Obviously it doesn't make any difference to what value sslVerify is set.

Further info: I'm on Windows 10 and use git 2.22.0. And it works in my cygwin bash, but not in git bash, cmd, git extensions, etc.

Comment: You realize that you set SSL verification to `true`? Don't you want `false`?

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error, It doesn't make any difference to what value sslVerify is set. I clarified this in my last edit.

Comment: Is it maybe this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064542/435093

Comment: Sadly it's not this problem, also, I don't want to use schannel, but indeed switch ssl verification off. Funny enough, if I use schannel, I get "fatal: unable to access 'https://git.kvb.local/git/ondes-dame/': Out of memory".

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this, not really a solution. The git client ignores all ssl configuration options AND always verifies certificates against "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt" AND this file does not exist and is not created when installing git. I had to create this file containing our self signed certificates to make it work. Under cygwin all ssl configuration options are also ignored, but another CA bundle file is used, because git calls the cygwin openssl client. We were able to track down the problem only after installing the git client in version 2.19, which prints the CA file on the console when an error occurred, while git 2.21 doesn't.

At the end, all problems vanished after downgrading to git 2.9., so I will stick to this version for the next time.